# Best Linux network tuning tips?

Tags: linux, networking, performance

I figure it's a good idea to have a central question for linux network tuning. I'm particularly interested in tuning options for the following.

1. Web server
2. Varnish / Squid server
3. DB server
4. File server
5. App server

Comment: So much of this is very subjective based on what you're actually doing/serving.

Comment: ... and different applications require different OS tuning. For example a fileserver on a lan should be configured with big buffers to server a moderate number of users quickly. Whereas a public website must be frugal with the amount of buffering offered to each connection to avoid resource starvation

Comment: That's why I'm looking for different suggestions for different servers, not a one size fits all.

Comment: Then ask separate questions.

Answer (score 5):

At this point it's generally not worth the overhead of "tuning" within the kernel. Unless you have the test gear (or a cluster to A/B options on) and *very* good documentation it's not worth it for the sys-admin overhead alone.

These days the linux kernel has good auto-tuning of TCP, you *can* do better, however those are not the default because they're seen to be "greedy" and not fair on the Internet.

As close as I get to tuning is:

1. Mount noatime (implies nodiratime), using ext3 or xfs
2. Run only needed services
3. For services like squid & mysql allow them to use more RAM

With rare exceptions those three will get you 90% there.

Answer (score 3):

network stack tuning i put on routers/firewalls connecting to net hundreds of users

```
net/ipv4/route/max_size=262144
net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=18000
net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_thresh1=1024
net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_thresh2=2048
net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_thresh3=4096
net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max=128000
net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_expect_max=4096
```

[ mostly empirically tweaked over years based on some unpleasant crashes ]

for file/sql/poroxy server you definitivly want to mount partition with data/spool with **noatime,nodiratime** and for reiserfs - notail ] to avoid additional disk trashing whenever file is accessed for read.

and you really want [ maybe you don't know about it yet ;-] gather statistics - eg with [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) - to do some capacity planning and see if your tuning indeed decreases system load.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may want to look at [web100](http://www.web100.org/).  It is a kernel patch, and a userland too designed to optimized the Linux kernel for high-performance networks.

> The Web100 project is aimed at
>   producing a complete host-software
>   environment that will run common Web
>   applications at 100% of the available
>   bandwidth, regardless of the magnitude
>   of a network's capability.

Also check out [High Performance SSH/SCP](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/hpn-ssh/).

> SCP and the underlying SSH2 protocol
>   implementation in OpenSSH is network
>   performance limited by statically
>   defined internal flow control buffers.
>   These buffers often end up acting as a
>   bottleneck for network throughput of
>   SCP, especially on long and high
>   bandwith network links. Modifying the
>   ssh code to allow the buffers to be
>   defined at run time eliminates this
>   bottleneck.